# How to apply all changes done in umbraco from one environment to another

Tags: umbraco, environment

I'm currently having difficulties in finding a way to do this. We're working with various different environments (DEV/QA..etc) and would like there to be a way to retrieve all changes made in umbraco on one environment and reflect them on a different environment using a different database as well.

Comment: You could use [uSync](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/developer-tools/usync/) + Data Comapre in Visual Studio to do that.

Comment: Using data compare is not an option considering some of the people using umbraco don't actually have it. I'm looking for a way to generate the changes in some form or another on a file within the platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way to do that "properly" is to use Umbraco Cloud, which supports moving things like changes AND content between different versions of the site.

For non-cloud users, your only real option is uSync for Umbraco changes (DocTypes etc), and then content you can try uSync Content edition, but your mileage may vary with that one, depending on how complex your site setup is. Note, uSync won't do things like CSS/JS changes or DLL changes, those you'll have to publish yourself.

Comment: Decided to go with this, uSync and uSync Content edition seems like my best bet

Comment: Since I wrote this, uSync complete has been announced, and that transfers EVERYTHING. It's paid for rather than free, but it seems to work VERY well.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually several ways to do this.

**1. Umbraco Courier**

Depending on the version of umbraco you are using you can use [Umbraco Courier](https://umbraco.com/apps/umbraco-courier/) it is the commercial tool created and maintained by Umbraco HQ. It works up to 7.12.0.

**2. Swap the database**

If you have more than one environment, you and want to move the content from one place to another, you can simply replace the umbraco database with one from another enviroment. Depending on your requirements you could set this up as an automated process using something like [Octopus deploy](https://octopus.com/) for example.

**3. uSync**

[uSync](https://our.umbraco.com/packages/developer-tools/usync/) Has been around for a long time in the Umbraco world and has compatibility for many versions of Umbraco including the very latest, its open source and you can install it from the back office in Umbraco or via nuget.

**4. Umbraco Cloud**

[Umbraco Cloud](https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-cloud) is not free, but I think the prices are reasonable for the service you get. Essentially Umbraco have set up a platform that allows you to create multiple environments and push content between them with just one click. I think its great, but it takes a little while to get used to how to leverage it properly. I would recommend building a project using the trial period and see if it meets your requirements. You get the benefits of upgrades carried out be Umbraco HQ and pretty good office hours tech support.